# Change hyperlink own text on its click event through jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a dynamically generated list of hyperlinks and i'm using jquery to bind the click events, everything is working fine, just one thing i am unable to do is to changes its text

```
 **this.value = s;**
```

This is what I was trying to do without any success.

My full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*="lnkStatus_"]').bind('click', SaveRequirmentStatus);
});

function SaveRequirmentStatus(event) {
    var itemID = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    var intProjectId = $('[id$="hdnProjectId"]').val();
    var idRequirment = itemID.split('_')[1];
    var idRequirementPhase = itemID.split('_')[2];
    var idPhaseStatus = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    if (intProjectId != '0' && idRequirment != '0' && idRequirementPhase != '0') {
        $.getJSON('handler/RequirementLifecycleHandler.ashx?     FuncName=SaveRequirment&idRequirment=' + idRequirment + "&idRequirementPhase=" + idRequirementPhase + "&idProject=" + intProjectId + "&idPhaseStatus=" + idPhaseStatus, function (ValueStatus) {
            var s = ValueStatus;
            alert(this);
            this.value = s;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in the context that you are using it does not refer to the link, so save a reference to it outside of the inner function and use that. Also, a link does not have a value, you can set the text using the jQuery [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

Changing your code to this should do what you want:

```
function SaveRequirmentStatus(event) {
    var $this = this; // save reference to the clicked link
    var itemID=$(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    var intProjectId=$('[id$="hdnProjectId"]').val();
    var idRequirment=itemID.split('_')[1];
    var idRequirementPhase=itemID.split('_')[2];
    var idPhaseStatus = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    if (intProjectId != '0' && idRequirment != '0' && idRequirementPhase != '0') {
        $.getJSON('handler/RequirementLifecycleHandler.ashx?FuncName=SaveRequirment&idRequirment=' + idRequirment + "&idRequirementPhase=" + idRequirementPhase + "&idProject=" + intProjectId + "&idPhaseStatus=" + idPhaseStatus, function(ValueStatus) {
            $this.text(ValueStatus); // set the text of the link to ValueStatus
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error or does it simply not do anything? If you add a breakpoint at `$this.text(ValueStatus);` does it ever get hit?

Comment: @user2553774 You should at least use `console.log` or firebug or any other tool to debug the code. Give out more info.

Comment: @RichardDalton I believe OP copied `var $this = this;` instead of adding the link code there.

Comment: I have put alert before and after this line, both alert firing but text is not being changed

Comment: @user2553774 Can you post the HTML that is clicked to fire this event?

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
$(function() {
$('[id*="lnkStatus_"]').bind('click', SaveRequirmentStatus); 

});
function SaveRequirmentStatus(event) {
 $(this).text(ValueStatus);
}
```

Comment: I have put alert before and after '$(this).text(ValueStatus);', both alert firing but text is not being changed